# Python WebSocket client for mWebSocket Server

Tags: python, html, sockets, websocket, arduino

I am trying to build a WebSocket client in python that connects to an Arduino Uno every second via an Ethernet cable, that has a WebSocket server on it, based on the mWebSocket library. The working Arduino code is shown below:

```
#include <WebSocketServer.h>
using namespace net;

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[]{0xA8, 0x61, 0x0A, 0xAE, 0x69, 0x13};
IPAddress ip(198, 162, 1, 177);
IPAddress gateway(0,0,0,0);
IPAddress DNSserver(0,0,0,0);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

constexpr uint16_t port = 80;
WebSocketServer wss{port};

void setup() {
  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
  
  Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino shields
  //Ethernet.init(5);   // MKR ETH shield
  //Ethernet.init(0);   // Teensy 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(20);  // Teensy++ 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(15);  // ESP8266 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet
  //Ethernet.init(33);  // ESP32 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("Ethernet WebServer Example");

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac,ip,DNSserver,gateway,subnet);

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
  }

  // start the server
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  wss.onConnection([](WebSocket & ws) {
    const auto protocol = ws.getProtocol(); 
    if (protocol) {
      Serial.print(F("Client protocol: "));
      Serial.println(protocol);
    }

    ws.onMessage([](WebSocket & ws, const WebSocket::DataType dataType,
    const char *message, uint16_t length) {
      switch (dataType) {
        case WebSocket::DataType::TEXT:
          Serial.print(F("Received: "));
          Serial.println(message);
          break;
        case WebSocket::DataType::BINARY:
          Serial.println(F("Received binary data"));
          break;
      }

      ws.send(dataType, message, length);
    });

    ws.onClose([](WebSocket &, const WebSocket::CloseCode, const char *,
    uint16_t) {
      Serial.println(F("Disconnected"));
    });

    Serial.print(F("New client: "));
    Serial.println(ws.getRemoteIP());

    const char message[] {"Hello from Arduino server!"};
    ws.send(WebSocket::DataType::TEXT, message, strlen(message));
  });

  wss.begin();
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  wss.listen();
}
```

I have constructed a python socket client to interact with this Arduino and hopefully print the message "Hello from Arduino server!" to the client with every connection.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import asyncio
import websockets
import socket
import time
import datetime
import struct

starttime = time.time() # start value for timed data acquisition

# setup socket 1
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1.connect(("198.162.1.177",80))
s1.sendall(b'GET / HTTP/1.1 400')
if True:
    print('Connected')
def acquire():
    
    data = s1.recv(10000)
    print(data)
        
while True:
   acquire()
   time.sleep(1.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1.0)) # continue every  (2.0 seconds)

s1.close()
```

However, when I run the above code. I obtain:

```
Connected
b'H'
b'TTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

What am I missing here, I presume that the connection is not being fully made, even though I can ping the Arduino from my PC. Do I need to account for a HTTP header in a different way for a WebSocket client?

Answer (score 0):

Websocket connection is made by a HTTP request with upgrade headers which specifies that the connecting client want's to upgrade to a websocket protocol. When the server receives this message and finding the upgrade headers in the request it validates if the upgrade it supported on it's end and upgrades the underlying connection to a websocket connection. This is the thing that seems to be missing from your end.

Also, as you are importing websockets in your client code. You can use the library functions which does this work for you and you just make a GET request with "ws/wss" specified in your request URL.

Comment: Ok I see, I am fairly new to socket communication so what do I need to add to the python script?